# Python extension module

Tags: python, python-3.x, distutils

I want to build package that consist of multiple extension sub-packages:

```
| root
| ----> a
        | ----> a1
        | ----> a2
| ----> b
| ----> c
```

As you can see one of the sub-package has it's own sub-packages. In the setup.py file I'm building the packages like this:

```
from distutils.core import setup
from distutils.core import Extension

modules = [
Extension('root.a.a', sources=['root/a/a.c']),
Extension('root.a.a1', sources=['root/a/a1.c']),
Extension('root.a.a2', sources=['root/a/a2.c']),
Extension('root.b', sources=['root/b/b.c']),
Extension('root.c', sources=['root/c/c.c']),
]

setup(
    ....
    packages=['root', 'root.a'],
    ....
    ext_modules=modules,
)
```

The package builds successfully. I can run python interpreter and import it, but when try to execute some method it get error:

```
>>> from root import b
>>> b.foo()
>>> AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'foo'
```

Also dir() doesn't show anything. Any idea where I'm wrong?

The sources of b.c is:

```
PyMethodDef module_methods[] = {
    { "foo",  (PyCFunction)py_foo, METH_VARARGS | METH_KEYWORDS, "Foobar" },
    { NULL,    NULL,         0,                NULL         }
};

#if PY_MAJOR_VERSION >= 3
static struct PyModuleDef module_def = {
    PyModuleDef_HEAD_INIT,
    "b",
    NULL,
    -1,
    module_methods
};
#endif

PyMODINIT_FUNC
#if PY_MAJOR_VERSION >= 3
PyInit_b(void)
{
#else
    initb(void) {
#endif
#pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-Wunused-but-set-variable"
    PyObject *module = NULL;

#if PY_MAJOR_VERSION >= 3
    module = PyModule_Create(&module_def);
#else
    module = Py_InitModule("b", module_methods);
#endif

#if PY_MAJOR_VERSION >= 3
    return module;
#else
    return;
#endif
```

Comment: It's hard to say if `foo` is really defined in `b` judging from what you posted.

Comment: @ElmoVanKielmo I updated the question